# how to convert this date 21 Nov 2016 1:53PM using NSDate formatter in objective c ?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdate

i want to separate out day month year time  how will i do

```
NSString *datefromweb = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"ContentDateTime"];

NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date1 = [dateformatter dateFromString:datefromweb];
NSLog(@"date1=%@",date1);
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];

NSString *month1 = [dateformatter stringFromDate:date1];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

NSString *time= [dateformatter stringFromDate:date1];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];

NSString *day1= [dateformatter stringFromDate:date1];

    cell.day.text=day1;
    cell.monthYear.text=month1;
    cell.ldatetime.text=time;
```

we get string in datefromweb(NSString) variable but not get in datefromstring(NSDate) variable and i am separate out date,time,month,year.

```
my response is {ContentDateTime = "02 Jul 2016  5:12PM";}
```

Comment: It's probably best if you used a standard timestamp format - you're not including the timezone?

Comment: `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm` doesn't match `02 Jul 2016  5:12PM`. Well, for the Day, Month and Year, it seems to, but not for the hours/minutes. So `date1` should be nil. And so nothing after should work. You wrote yourself afterwards `hh:mm a`, so you know how to get AM/PM, no? So the good format was something like `dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a`.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateComponents. Try this code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy  hh:mma"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"02 Jul 2016  5:12PM"];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comonents =
[cal components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond
                       ) fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [comonents day];
NSInteger month = [comonents month];
NSInteger year = [comonents year];
NSInteger hour = [comonents hour];
NSInteger minutes = [comonents minute];
NSInteger seconds = [comonents second];
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code sorry for late answer. Just Change the date format.

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
 [formatter setDateFormat"dd MMM yyyy  hh:mma"];
```